# Extra space on left & right side in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I'm refactoring a webpage now, and the width of webpage is fixed to 980px.

look at the image below. While browsing my web in mobile devices, the page occupied full width of screen.

[image]

Is there any simple idea to archive the appearance in the second picture? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: i recommended to use width:100%; instead of fixed width

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to detect the screen with and add extra space for it.
For example in a mobile screen of 1024 px width use less space, 900px maybe:

```
  @media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .container{
        width: 900px;
    }
  }
```

You can read more about media queries here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries